# How can I prevent the iPad from getting my iPhone texts or calls?

Tags: iphone, ios

Updated my iPhone and iPad to IOS 8.0.2 and now when I get a text or phone call on the iPhone the message appears on my iPad. Can I undo or unlink this feature?

Answer (score 2):

On the iPad simply go to 'setting', then 'messages', then slide 'iMessages' to off.  You will not receive texts from anyone.

Answer (score 1):

for messages the solution is:
on iPhone - settings/messages
then text message forwarding.
you will see devices listed to receive your texts.
just toggle off which devices you don't want to receive you copy texts.

this wont affect i message, just all the other texts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go in to message settings on the iPad, then go to send and receive  and deselect your phone number.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Under "Send & Receive" you will actually see that this is the screen where you are signed in to iMessage with your iCloud account. Sign out. This is quite annoying, because in the overall Settings screen you already have spots to sign into and out of iTunes Store and iCloud, plus signing into iCloud under "Mail, Contacts, Calendars". This is now the 4th screen where you need to manage signing in to your Apple account.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing the settings for messaging on the iPhone, you should go into settings on the iPad, go to facetime and turn off iPhone cellular calls.

Answer (score -2):

For iMessage just tap Settings, then Messages, then simply move the slider button to stop iMessages from going to your iPad!